# Namespace-level access

Tags: c++, namespaces, access-modifiers

I have the following situation:

```
namespace MyFramework {
  class A {
    void some_function_I_want_B_to_use() {}
  };
  class B {
    B() {
      some_function_I_want_B_to_use() {}
    }
  };
}
```

where I want the `some_function_I_want_B_to_use` to not be visible outside of the `MyFramework` namespace, but I do want it to be visible to anyone inside of MyFramework (alternatively, visible to just class B is also ok). I've got a number of methods like this, is the only way to hide them from the public API of MyFramework to make all classes within `MyFramework` friends? I was also considering placing all "lower-level" classes inside of B, but I don't want to go down that route until I'm sure it would accomplish the ability to access all of A's methods from inside of B but not from outside of MyFramework.

To restate, I've got a framework that's all created within one namespace, and each class has methods that are useful to the general public using the framework. However, each class also has a few methods that complicate the public API but are needed for the framework to function properly.

Comment: What does "visible" mean? If the function's name can be found in the header file but the function is `private`, is it visible?

Comment: No (for my purposes). I'd like to be able to list the "public" api as being only public methods. E.g. having 3 public methods makes the use of the class clear, but having 20+ methods makes the class usage a lot less obvious

Comment: does some_function_I_want_B_to_use need to be a method of A? or could it be a namespace function in MyFramework?

Comment: Hm...interesting thought. Many of the "some_function..." options are accessing private variables inside of their respective classes. However I could probably use getters to remove this requirement and pull quite a few of them into the namespace itself. Might be a valid approach if there is no better way :-)

Comment: I forget if this will grant the classes access to each other's private data members, but what if MyFramework was a class instead, and under that was each class (with appropriate members being private)? Alternately, I think a facade (design pattern) is exactly for this situation; if you are willing to create a public facade for each class, this is a good option

Comment: @Rollie - that's actually my current approach: There is really only one core "class B" that's used by the public, and I've been adding methods to B that allow facade-level access to other bits of the system. It's not very pretty so far, so I was searching for a different method. However your comment makes me think of another possible solution: having a "public proxy class" for each of the internal classes. Then I can point to "public interface of B + these 5 proxy classes" as the intended API

Comment: If MyFramework is a class, then all of MyFramework's private members are accessible by all of MyFramework's subclasses, via MyFramework::s for static, and MyFrameworkInstance.x for instances.  That might be the direction you want to go...

Comment: @EHuhtala - Don't think so...I doubt an inner(assuming you mean inner, not sub) class of MyFramework would be able to access the private fields of another inner class of MyFramework. It just brings back the original point that perhaps using friend classes is the "right" way to tackle this challenge, although my understanding is that they are not intended for use with OO code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pimpl idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer), frequently called **Compilation Firewall**, is what you are looking for. The whole [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) is implemented using this idiom.

```
// A.hpp
namespace MyFramework {
  class A {
  private:
    class Private;

    Private* implementation;
  };
}

// A_Private.hpp
#include "A.hpp"

namespace MyFramework {
  class A::Private {
  public:
    void some_function_I_want_B_to_use() {}
  };
}

// A.cpp
#include "A_Private.hpp"

namespace MyFramework {
A::A() {
  implementation->some_function_I_want_B_to_use();
}
}

// B.hpp
#include "A.hpp"

namespace MyFramework {
  class B {
    B();

    A a;
  };
}

// B.cpp
#include "A_Private.hpp"

namespace MyFramework {
B::B() {
  a.implementation->some_function_I_want_B_to_use();
}
}
```

**NOTE**: Of course `A_Private.hpp` does not go into the `include` directory of you framework final distribution, i.e. it remains **package private** as you require.

The example is very basic. Of course it can be made more advanced and robust. Additionally, **Pimpl** has lots of other advantages. For all this information refer to:

- [GotW #100: Compilation Firewalls (Difficulty: 6/10)](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/)
- [GotW #101: Compilation Firewalls, Part 2 (Difficulty: 8/10)](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_101/)
- [Pimp My Pimpl — Reloaded](http://marcmutz.wordpress.com/translated-articles/pimp-my-pimpl-%E2%80%94-reloaded/)
- [Pimp My Pimpl](http://marcmutz.wordpress.com/translated-articles/pimp-my-pimpl/)
- [Dpointer](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Dpointer)

Comment: what if a header-only module is desired?

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf, Then, you are out of luck, and this is the exact reason why `Boost` uses `detail` namespace convention (slight overhead is another reason). However, the author did not provide such a requirement, therefore this solution perfectly fits his question.

Answer (score 4):

> I want the `some_function_I_want_B_to_use` to not be visible outside of the `MyFramework` namespace, but I do want it to be visible to anyone inside of `MyFramework`.

In summary, you want something similar to packages in Java.

Unfornately for you, that is *not* possible with namespaces. Every class included in a namespace is accessible from the outer of the namespace: namespaces are open.

The solution is usually to add another namespace for implementation details:

```
namespace MyFramework
{
    // Implementation details
    // Should not be used by the user
    namespace detail
    {
        class A
        {
            public:
                void func();
        };
    }

    class B
    {
        public:
            B()
            {
                A a;
                a.func();
            }
    };
}
```

Don't forget to add a comment stating the `detail` namespace is not to be used by user.

Answer (score 2):

The common convention, e.g. in Boost, is a nested namespace called `detail`.

If you want to *enforce* the accessibility you can always instead use a nested `class` called `detail`. The class provides accessibility checking, but lacks extensibility like a namespace. However, a `detail` scope will rarely if ever need extension.

So, in all its ugliness,

```
namespace my_framework {
    class detail
    {
    private:
        static void some_function_I_want_B_to_use() {}

    public:
        class A
        {};

        class B
        {
            B() { some_function_I_want_B_to_use(); }
        };
    };

    typedef detail::A A;        // "using detail::A"
    typedef detail::B B;        // "using detail::B"
}  // namespace my_framework
```

---

In passing, note that class B (straight from the question) has a private default constructor so no instances of it can be created.